# Proving the least upper bound of a subset X of 2^S

Tags: order-theory, supremum-and-infimum, upper-lower-bounds

Consider set S and the power set $2^S$.
The least upper bound of a subset X of $2^S$ is $\cup X$.

As any example, suppose $S=\{a,b,c\}$. Then consider $X=\{\{a,b\},\{c\}\}$ s.t. $X\subseteq 2^S$.
Clearly, the least upper bound is the set $\{a,b,c\}$.

However, I am having difficulties proving this statement. Could anyone give me some pointers on how this can be done?

Comment: The "least upper bound" (lub) concept is connected with $2^S$ considered as a **lattice** induced by (partial) ordering due to order relationship $\subset$.

Comment: Being a “least upper bound” means being an upper bound and the least one of all upper bounds.